# What is the number of clock cycles required in the given sequence of Instruction using 5- stage pipelined CPU?

Tags: cpu-architecture, instructions, pipelining

A 5 stage pipelined CPU has the following sequence of stages:

- IF – Instruction fetch from instrution memory.
- RD – Instruction decode and register read.
- EX – Execute: ALU operation for data and address computation.
- MA – Data memory access – for write access, the register read at RD state is
  used.
- WB – Register write back.

Consider the following sequence of instructions:

```
I1: L  R0, loc 1       ; R0 <=M[loc1]
I2: A  R0, R0 1        ; R0 <= R0 + R0
I3: S  R2, R0 1        ; R2 <= R2 - R0
```

Let each stage take one clock cycle.
What is the number of clock cycles taken to complete the above sequence of
instructions starting from the fetch of I1?

So here's my solution.

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
I1: IF  RD  EX  MA  WB
I2:     IF  -   -   -   RD  EX  MA  WB
I3:         IF  -   -   -   -   -   -   RD  EX  MA  WB
```

In this way I'm getting total 13 cycles. I'm assuming that since operand forwarding is not explicitly mentioned in the question. So register will be only available after WB stage. But option are following:

- A. 8
- B. 10
- C. 12
- D. 15

Comment: If you're going to post a homework question, at least demonstrate that you've done some work on it (other than transcribing it to SO). Do you have an answer of any kind (maybe that doesn't match the expected result)?

Comment: Yes, I have solved it but my answer in not matching any of the options given. Ok I will also put my solution.

Comment: Good - because otherwise it looks like you've done *no* work, and just want to be handed an answer, rather than gain the understanding that the problem is meant to demonstrate.

Comment: Ok now I have included my solution with the question.

Comment: I don't think the instructions after the 2nd and 3rd IF need to be pushed so far to the right. Can you motivate why you did that?

Comment: RD stage of I2 will be using R0 register. That will be only available after WB stage that is register write back. So RD stage will take place in next clock cycle to WB of I1. Similarly for I2 and I3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The given problem is based on structural hazard because of the below line*

" **MA – Data memory access – for write access, the register read at RD state is used** "

and not on data dependency although it seems to have data dependency. And hence, nothing is mentioned about data forwarding in the question.

Structural hazard is for the load instruction. And hence the execution of the next instruction cannot start until the execution of the first instruction, because the effective address of the memory location referred by **M[loc1]** will be calculated only during the execution phase of the pipeline. So till then the bus will not be freed and hence the second instruction cannot be fetched. Thus second instruction will take extra **2 clock cycles**.

And the third instruction cannot start execution till the first instruction successfully loads the data to register R0. Which results the third instruction to have **3 more clock** cycles.

```
Hence, total clock cycles = (CC for I1) + (CC for I2) + (CC for I3) 
= 5 + 2 + 3
= 10 clock cycles
```

Comment: Cant we use Operand Forwarding here ?

Answer (score 2):

For Write access the register read at RD stage is used- this means if we cannot operand forwards a value to MA stage. So, we can assume operand forwarding can be done for other stages.

With data forwarding:

T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  T7  T8

IF  RD  EX  MA  WB
-IF RD   -   EX MA  WB
--IF    -    RD EX  MA  WB

Hence, answer will be 8.

http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/PIPELINE/forward.html